# Unity: Assets are "pixelated" but the Assets are in high quality

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need your help. My Assets are looking bad in the Scene and Gameview.(Lines are pixelated)
If I zoom to my Assets the Quality is fine.

Can someone help me? I was thing the Problem is because I downscaled my Asset.

[image: Zoomed Picture]

[image: This is like it looks]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. You need to Generate Mip Maps for your assets.